# Observable that wraps FromEventPattern while caching the most recent event for new subscribers

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have created an observable by using `Observable.FromEventPattern`. Let's call it `fromEvents`.

I want to create another observable that wraps `fromEvents`. We'll call this 2nd observable `wrapper`.

When `wrapper` is subscribed to it should:

1. Publish the most recent item from `fromEvents` if any.
2. Publish the rest of items coming from `fromEvents`

Obviously `wrapper` will need to maintain a subscription to `fromEvents` so that it always has access to the most recent event.

I have tried various combinations of `Replay`, `Publish`, `PublishLast`, `Observable.Defer` and I'm never quite getting the results I'm looking for.

I'm certain Rx has operators that will meet my needs, I'm just unsure of exactly how to put everything together, being the newb that I am.

Comment: Did you try [Publish(initialValue) overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211622(v=vs.103).aspx)? What part of it did not suit your needs?

Comment: That seems wrong to me. http://goo.gl/M3g8CE says, "Publish makes a cold observable hot." and also, "any .NET event can be made into a hot observable simply by calling FromEventPattern, without using Publish." I already have a hot observable. I know that much. I think I want a cold observable that has the side effect of "yielding" the most recently (cached) value from the underlying observable. Besides, PublishLast that takes an initial value requires the initial value, which I may not have yet, if the underlying observable hasn't yet yielded anything.

Comment: And anyway, Publish(initValue), doesn't do what I'm describing.

Comment: Publish is useful on hot observables also. This particular overload does what you want. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've been able to get what I want by doing this:

```
Events = Observable.FromEventPattern(...).Replay(1).RefCount();

// contrived example
// in my real app the subscription lives for a specific duration
// and Events is exposed as a readonly property
using(Events.Subscribe())
{
     // get most recent or wait for first
    var e = Events.FirstAsync().Wait();
}
```

Comment: yes `Replay(1)` is probably better than `Publish(null).Where(e => e != null)`.  Too many ways to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Example using the Publish overload that uses a BehaviorSubject behind the scenes to keep track of the most recent event.

```
var fromEvents = Observable.FromEventPattern(...);
var published = fromEvents.Publish(null);
// subscribe to this one
var wrapper = published.Where(e => e != null);
// start collecting values
var subscription = published.Connect();

wrapper.Subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think I have gotten it working in a bit of a simpler way. Please see my answer and let me know if there are any pitfalls that I'm not aware of.